# Interfaces and address operators

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface

I have a problem to understand why the address operator can be used when the return type is an interface

```
func NewReader() IReader {
    return &Reader{}
}
```

but (of course) not when a return type is a struct

```
func NewReader() Reader {
    return &Reader{} // cannot use &Reader literal (type *Reader) as type Reader in return argument
}
```

The function signature later is `func MyFuncReader(r IReader)` but the `reflect.TypeOf(r)` is `*main.Reader`.

1. So the type `IReader` is hiding the fact that it is pointer?
2. The function signature `func MyFuncReader(r IReader)` doesn't tell me, that a pointer or a value was passed the func?

Samples

1. Full Sample with interface https://play.golang.org/p/1Db1Jybp0rP
2. Full Sample without interface  https://play.golang.org/p/nPtu09yhe0C

Comment: It's already implicit that people can suggest how to improve questions. Asking probably won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the return type of a function is an interface type, you may return any values that implement that interface. [Spec: Return statements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)

> The return value or values may be explicitly listed in the "return" statement. Each expression must be single-valued and [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the corresponding element of the function's result type.

In your first example `Reader` has methods with **pointer receiver**, so only a pointer to `Reader` (that is `*Reader`) implements the `IReader` interface. So you *have* to return `&Reader{}`.

If your function has a return type of a concrete type, you have to return a value of that exact concrete type, you can't return a value of a pointer to that type.

Comment: How do I know if I'm passing a pointer or a create a new copy of data, if an interface can be both. When using pointer receiver or value receiver.

Comment: @dhcgn If both the pointer and non-pointer types implement the interface, then both works. Which should be used depends on the case.

Answer (score 1):

When the return type is a `Reader`

> ```
> func NewReader() Reader {
>     return &Reader{} // cannot use &Reader literal (type *Reader) as type Reader in return argument
> }
> ```

you cannot use a pointer to a `Reader` type in place of a `Reader` type. The reason being they are just not of the same type.

When you use an interface like `IReader` as a return type as in

> ```
> func NewReader() IReader {
>     return &Reader{}
> }
> ```

it basically means that **any** type implementing the methods of the `IReader` interface will classify as a type implementing that interface and thus will be acceptable. Since the type `*Reader` implements the `IReader` type in your example, it is an acceptable return value of the NewReader function here. That means if I introduce a new `type` which implements this interface, such as,

```
type dummy int

func (d dummy) GetCount() int {
    return d
}

func (d dummy) IncreaseCount() {
    fmt.Println("Increased count: %d", d)
}
```

then I can do something like

```
func NewReader() IReader {
    var d dummy
    d = 5
    return d
}
```

and it would still work. The underlying type of this returned value on checking using the `reflect` package will be `dummy`.

Comment: Does this make it harder see if I'm working with values or references?

Comment: @dhcgn I'm not sure why you would think that. Maybe tell me the reason for the same please? Also, if it's the pointer `*Reader` that implements the interface, a `Reader` value type won't be an acceptable value as a `IReader` return type. However, if it's the `Reader` which implements the interface both the `*Reader` and `Reader` are acceptable return types, because afaik go can interpret that it's the `Reader` that implements the interface and can take the underlying value from `*Reader`.

Comment: You may find [this](https://tour.golang.org/methods/6) and [this](https://tour.golang.org/methods/7) helpful.